# Jaspersoft Studio doesn't support the artifact tag. Is there a workaround?

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, artifact, jaspersoft-studio

It seems Jaspersoft does not support the artifact tag supported by Adobe PDF Reader. In our report, we want screen readers to ignore reading "header and footer"  on each page. Currently, it seems Jaspersoft does not support the artifact tag to ignore these fields.

Is there a workaround? Each page contains headers and footers. Sometimes our dynamic tables span across multiple pages. Currently, screen readers are reading all the page header and footer elements while reading the table.